# php unserialize not working

Tags: php, serialization

I have very strange situation.
I am parsing hidden input and get this string:

```
a:2:{s:12:"subscription";a:5:{s:6:"gender";i:1;s:4:"name";i:1;s:7:"company";i:1;s:5:"email";i:1;s:11:"receiveHtml";i:1;}s:6:"submit";i:1;}d35ea44253419bbb6a8be13422eb606ad54121f4
```

it comes from this

```
preg_match_all('/hidden" name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"/', $html, $hiddenResults);
```

and when I try unserialize it returns false, but if I just set it to variable manualy and unserialize - it works!! what a problem ?

I have noticed this:

```
string(248) "a:2:{s:12:"subscription";a:5:{s:6:"gender";i:1;s:4:"name";i:1;s:7:"company";i:1;s:5:"email";i:1;s:11:"receiveHtml";i:1;}s:6:"submit";i:1;}d35ea44253419bbb6a8be13422eb606ad54121f4" 
string(178) "a:2:{s:12:"subscription";a:5:{s:6:"gender";i:1;s:4:"name";i:1;s:7:"company";i:1;s:5:"email";i:1;s:11:"receiveHtml";i:1;}s:6:"submit";i:1;}d35ea44253419bbb6a8be13422eb606ad54121f4"
```

Same strings has different length! How is it possible ?

Comment: Is there any change that you upload bigger snippet of your code?

Comment: It really has no matter! Please take a look, same strings, length is different

Comment: There may be some hidden characters in the first string.

Comment: How can I see that ?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions, use http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("&quot;", '"', $hiddenValues[$i]);
```

it has solved the problem